# Kill a process remotely using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, remote-server

please help me as i need to kill/ restart a process remotely.

I have tried this but no luck for me. Error was - "Couldn't connect to remote machine"

```
Process[] prs = Process.GetProcesses("SERVERNAME");

   foreach (Process pr in prs)
    {
       if (pr.ProcessName == "process")
       {
           pr.Kill();
       }
    }
```

I also try this one but still doesn't work and got this error:
 "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\SERVERNAME\\root\\cimv2");
scope.Connect();
ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name='process'");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
ManagementObjectCollection objectCollection = searcher.Get();

   foreach (ManagementObject managementObject in objectCollection)
      {
       managementObject.InvokeMethod("Terminate", null);
      }
```

I hope someone has a solution for this.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the errors are actually telling you exactly what's wrong. Your application is failed connecting to the remote machine. This can happen for some reasons:

1. The remote computer is unavailable (not exists)
2. The remote computer doesn't have WMI open for remote connection, or it's firewall-ed on the remote machine or on the way.
3. You don't have a permission to perform this action. Since i don't see anywhere in your code impersonation, then the connection will be using the current process token (which account it is? depends on your configuration on the application pool, or in your web.config if you use  tag, by default - it's NT AUTHORITY). You probably don't have permissions to access the remote machine using WMI with the credentials you're running at. It can be solved by impersonation in your code, in the web.config, or in the application pool settings to an account which has the sufficient permission (if you're in domain, ask your IT department for an account).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `web.config` with the appropriate account (the one with permissions).

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="UserWithPermissions" password="pw" />
```